# NodeJS how to create a bash like input

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to create a nodejs cli app, where there is a shell.

I have tried doing this so far:

```js
readline.question('> ', val => {
  console.log(val)
  readline.close();
});
```

But it only works once, how do I make it work continuously?

Like so:

```
> Hello
Hello
> World
World
```

Comment: readline's create interface sounds similar to what ur talking about ;-;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is happening because you are only calling the question function once. To ask for next input you need to call it again inside the callback. I would create a recursive function like this:

```
function askQuestion(){
readline.question('> ', val => {
  
  console.log(val);
  askQuestion() // ask next question
});
}

askQuestion() // initialize question terminal
```

If you also need a command to exit out of question loop, you can even add a breaking condition like this

```
function askQuestion(){
readline.question('> ', val => {
  if(val==='exit'){ //breaking condition
 
    readline.close()
    return;
  }
  console.log(val);
  askQuestion() // ask next question
});
}

askQuestion() // initialize question terminal
```